# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' even when it does not detect any

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying to apply unsupervised learning to a database containing already cleaned tweets in the text_clean column. However, when I do fit of the X I get the error shown in the title. This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Cargamos los datos desde un archivo csv
df = pd.read_csv("nombre_del_archivo.csv")

# Eliminamos las filas con valores nulos en cualquier columna
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Reemplazamos cualquier valor nulo que quede en la columna 'text_clean' con una cadena vacía
df['text_clean'].fillna('', inplace=True)

# Aplicamos un modelo de aprendizaje no supervisado para agrupar los tuits por clusters
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text_clean'])

# Evaluamos el valor óptimo de clusters de 2 a 10 y lo aplicamos
wcss = []
for i in range(2, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
```

I have my error here

```
wcss = []
for i in range(2, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    
plt.plot(range(2, 11), wcss)
plt.title('Método del codo')
plt.xlabel('Número de clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

I get this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' even though I have checked that there is no nonetype or empty value. Here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'csr_matrix'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-f1e874523304> in <module>
      3 for i in range(2, 11):
      4     kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
----> 5     kmeans.fit(X)
      6     wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
      7 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1415         self._validate_params()
   1416 
-> 1417         X = self._validate_data(
   1418             X,
   1419             accept_sparse="csr",

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    544             raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
    545         elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 546             X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
    547             out = X
    548         elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    877                     array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    878                 else:
--> 879                     array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
    880             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    881                 raise ValueError(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py in _asarray_with_order(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    183     if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    184         # Use NumPy API to support order
--> 185         array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186         return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187     else:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any idea what I can do? thank you.

Any idea what I can do? thank you.

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: For start, edit your question and post full traceback you get. Ideally, post sample data that reproduce the problem

Comment: Which part of **post full traceback you get** is unclear?

Comment: As others have said it is difficult to debug this without seeing the full traceback and/or a sample of your data. However, it looks to me like your code should work if `X` contains valid data. I would suggest checking that `X` contains at least `n_clusters` number of samples. If it doesn't it might be because too much data is being filtered out when you remove and replace `NA` values in the dataframe